# How to shift date and time column by 6 hours in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have a date and time column which follows 24 hour format. Now I want it to shift it by 6 hours, such that 6 am of the current day becomes 00:00 and the day completes on 6 am of the following day. In excel, if we subtract 0.25 from the date column, it directly shifts the dates by 6 hours. But similar functionality doesn't seem to work in R. How does one achieve this in R?

Comment: could you share some of your data, eg paste some of it using `dput` (to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)) ?

Comment: DateTime
2/10/2016 19:18
2/10/2016 19:15
2/10/2016 19:12
2/10/2016 19:09
2/10/2016 19:06
2/10/2016 19:03



Updated
2/10/2016 13:18
2/10/2016 13:15
2/10/2016 13:12
2/10/2016 13:09
2/10/2016 13:06
2/10/2016 13:03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide more information on your question, like the data you're using.

To replicate that with R, you could use the lubridate package :

```
library(lubridate)

new_time <- time - hms("06:00:00")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

A solution using base R. By default arithmetic operations add seconds, so:

```
now <- Sys.time() #gets the current time
now
  "2016-04-22 09:52:21 CEST"
now + 6*3600      
  "2016-04-22 15:52:21 CEST"
```

With your data, you can try, around `strptime`:

```
df <- read.table(text="
DateTime
2/10/2016 19:18
2/10/2016 19:15
2/10/2016 19:12
2/10/2016 19:09
2/10/2016 19:06
2/10/2016 19:03", sep=";", h=T)

df
DateTime
1 2/10/2016 19:18
2 2/10/2016 19:15
3 2/10/2016 19:12
4 2/10/2016 19:09
5 2/10/2016 19:06
6 2/10/2016 19:03
df$NewTime <- strptime(as.character(df$DateTime), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 6*3600

df
DateTime             NewTime
1 2/10/2016 19:18 2016-10-03 01:18:00
2 2/10/2016 19:15 2016-10-03 01:15:00
3 2/10/2016 19:12 2016-10-03 01:12:00
4 2/10/2016 19:09 2016-10-03 01:09:00
5 2/10/2016 19:06 2016-10-03 01:06:00
6 2/10/2016 19:03 2016-10-03 01:03:00
```

You could remove the `as.character` step with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.table`.
Does it solve your problem?